# show the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sqrt x}$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

show the integral  $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sqrt x}$ converges

well I was thinking the only way is to get its antiderivative and calculate the integral, however, I don't know where to start.

Comment: Plot the function

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua Well I checked the plot and it appears it goes to -$\infty$ as the x goes to 0.... but I'm pretty sure it converges by the way the question was asked

Comment: Converges according to WolframAlpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E1+%5Cfrac%7B%5Cln%28%5Csin+x%29%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D%7D+dx

Comment: @Enver Yea I see that but I was looking for a way to prove it converges or calculate it analytically...

Comment: @MosaicJ I'm sure that would be difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use integration by parts to show that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(\sin x)}{\sqrt x} dx = 2\sqrt{x}\ln(\sin x)\Big|_0^1 - \int_0^1 2\sqrt x \cot x \ dx. \tag{a}$$

The value

$$2 \sqrt x \ln(\sin x) \Big|_0^1 = 2\ln(\sin 1) - 2\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt x \ln(\sin x).$$

The limit on the right hand side here can be shown to equal $0$. Use the Sandwich Theorem (or Squeeze Theorem) by noticing $x/2 \leq \sin x \leq x$ on $0 \leq x \leq 1$ implies

$$\sqrt x\ln(x/2) \leq \sqrt x \ln (\sin x) \leq \sqrt x \ln x,$$

for $0 < x \leq 1$, and then proving

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt x \ln x = \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt x \ln (x/2) = 0$$

using L'Hopital's Rule.

We then focus on the integral in (a) on the right hand side. It suffices to show that this integral is finite. Using the $u$-sub $u = \sqrt{x}$, we obtain

$$\int_0^1 2\sqrt{x} \cot x \ dx = \int_0^1 4u^2\cot u^2 \ du.$$

Now, notice that $u^2\cot u^2$ is defined and finite for $u$ in $0 < u \leq 1$. Additionally,

$$\lim_{u \to 0} u^2\cot u^2 = \lim_{u \to 0} \cos u^2\left(\frac{u^2}{\sin u^2} \right) = 1,$$

where we use the well-known result

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac {\sin t}t = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac t{\sin t} = 1.$$

Thus, both the evaluation and the integral in (a) is finite, which implies the convergence of the original integral.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem could be around $x=0$.

Close to $x=0$, $\sin(x)\sim x$, $\log(\sin(x))\sim \log(x)$ so, we face more or less
$$\int \frac {\log(x)}{\sqrt x}\,dx$$

Integrate by parts $$\int \frac {\log(x)}{\sqrt x}\,dx= \sqrt{x}\, (2 \log (x)-4)$$ No problem.

**Edit**

I do not think that an antiderivative exist. Consider a Taylor expansion around $x=0$
$$\log(\sin(x))=\log
   (x)-\frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x^4}{180}-\frac{x^6}{2835}-\frac{x^8}{37800}+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$ and integrate termwise.

Look what happens when you expand the logarithm to $O(x^{2n})$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -4 & -4.00000000000 \\
 1 & -\frac{61}{15} & -4.06666666667 \\
 2 & -\frac{659}{162} & -4.06790123457 \\
 3 & -\frac{299849}{73710} & -4.06795550129 \\
 4 & -\frac{50974369}{12530700} & -4.06795861364 \\
 5 & -\frac{7065047897}{1736755020} & -4.06795881724 \\
 6 & -\frac{1018997296451}{250493512500} & -4.06795883167 \\
 7 & -\frac{384161980864027}{94436054212500} & -4.06795883275 \\
 8 & -\frac{25354690737550247}{6232779578025000} & -4.06795883284 \\
 9 & -\frac{3368801694231686097349}{828130724193447675000} & -4.06795883284 \\
 10 & -\frac{690604347317590078188457}{169766798459656773375000} & -4.06795883284
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you! so is there such a "borderline" or threshold value to determine if x is "small enough" so that x = sin(x)?

Comment: @MosaicJ. We are looking what happens very very close to $x=0$